# material-ui dynamically change palette color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI with my ReactJS web app. I need to change the global palette primary color but unsure how to accomplish this. All help is appreciated.

```
Material-UI v1.0
React v16.3.2
Redux v3.7.2
React Router Dom v4.2.2
```

Thanks